# MySql Update All Fields But One

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a bunch of fields that will change daily (new one added or old ones deleted). I need to know how to update all fields except the primary key to NULL. Here is an example of my table.

```
id = Primary Key
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
```

All the fields except the primary key have default value of NULL. I need to do this for only certain records. So changing the table definition would not work.

```
Update table set <all fields except id> = NULL where id=12
```

Comment: Which conditions define which records are to be modified?

Comment: Every field needs to be changed to NULL (the default value) except the primary key called id.

Comment: there's no way to tell MySQL to update every field *except* one... you have to provide the field list manually (or write a script in another language that constructs the field list on run-time)

Answer (score 1):

```
update your_table
set field1 = null, field2 = null, field3 = null
where id = 123
```

Comment: This will not work, field1 for example may be deleted and this statement would fail.

Comment: If you change your table definition at runtime you should change your strategy. The table definition should be fixed.

Comment: @EricSietsema You cannot "delete" a column. You can `ALTER` the `TABLE` though and `DROP` a `COLUMN`. Is this what you are going to be doing, altering the table often?

Comment: Yes the table will be altered all the time, sorry for not using the correct term.

Answer (score 1):

```
update yourTable
set field1 = null, field2 = null, ... -- Every field you need
where ... -- The conditions that define which records you are going to update
```

Comment: This will not work as field1, may have been deleted. Some other fields, field 25 may have been added since the command was written. The table is always changing.

Comment: what do you mean by "changing"? if it means that columns are being added to your table, then you have a **very big** problem with your database design, and should take a look on database normalization